# Curved Box from one side in Word

Tags: ms-word

I am trying to make a template for my company's profile. I want to make rectangle curved from one side. As shown in the figure below. The blue box is a `rectangle` and the curved line is a `curve` in word. How can I ignore/delete the highlighted area in MSWord?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using an image instead of the built in shapes. Insert the image, set the height to the full height of the page and set the text-wrapping so it is behind the text. Here's a sample image to try.

[image: a tall blue arc]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a curved line, use a filled oval shape in front of the rectangle.  You might need to use the numeric fields in the Format tab to get the size you need.  Also, if you put these elements in the header, they won't get in your way when editing your docs.